# Unable to upload files using karate framework

Tags: api, file-upload, karate

i am using the below code to upload the file along with the json parameter passed. But i am unable to upload the file . Sometime the code works fine, the appropriate data is created but the File is not coming as attachment there.

Code :
Given multipart field metadata = { ArticleAbstract: 'New article API' , ArticleTitle: 'New article API' , ContentBody: 'New article API' , ArticleLanguage: 'en' , CategoryIDs: ['TAX-2','TAX-3'] , ContentType: 'Authored' }
And  multipart file myFile =  { read: '\Test.pdf' , filename: 'Test.pdf' , contentType: 'application/pdf' }
And header Content-Type = 'multipart/mixed'
When method POST
Then status 201

Any suggestions on this

Comment: multipart is tricky. we will try make this easier in the future. but for now the only option is for you to work closely with the server-side team and get the whole request correct. if you can post a cURL request that works that will help others give you a solution.